# What is the meaning and solution for making constructor which takes int argument and which also calling the main constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor

I hava a task but I don't really know what should I do:
Mars class is given. Define constructor which takes *int* type argument and which also calling 2-argument constructor (the main constructor)

```
 public class Mars
    {
        private string name;
        private int mass;
        public Mars() { }
        public Mars(string s; int m){name = s; mass = m;}
    }
```

Is this really possible? Could someone provide me an example of such a structure, please?

Comment: -1: While Jon (+1) gives nice answer, the question itself shows a some lack of effort - very first link searching for "C# constructor" - [Using Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173115(v=vs.110).aspx) explains and shows details of exactly this call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's describing *constructor chaining*, which is performed using `this` (to chain to another constructor in this class) or `base` (to chain to a base class constructor) before the body of the constructor:

```
public Mars(int m) : this("Some default name", m)
{
}
```

Note that your two-parameter constructor declaration is currently invalid, by the way - you need a comma to separate parameters, not a semi-colon. I'd also *strongly* recommend that you stick to one statement per line:

```
public Mars(string s, int m)
{
    name = s;
    mass = m;
}
```

For more details about constructor chaining, read [my article on the topic](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html).

Comment: Thank you. I will use that knowledge.